# {Lint Error} Cannot resolve symbol 'View.OnClickListener' in event handling

Tags: android, lint

I have a variable in my data binding as shown below and I am performing onClick operation in the ImageView.
I am getting a lint error warning in Android Studio that it is not able to resolve 'View.OnClickListener'. Is there a way I can remove this warning?

```
<data>  
    <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="View.OnClickListener" />
</data>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> clickListener.onClick(v)}"
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
<variable
  name="clickListener"
  type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
```

And

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:onClick="@{clickListener::onClick}" />
```